# Identifying the Pivot Table fields for each row (Excel)

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have a data table, and this corresponding pivot table:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExzBX.png]

For each row in the pivot table, I'd like to know which field the row label refers to. So for the highlighted orange cell C17, I would like to return "First Name" (as you can see by hovering over cell A17).

I have some constraints that mean I need to use the pivot table in compact form. It would be easy if I could just use an outline or tabular layout, but I'm restricted to using a single column for my row labels.

Any ideas please? I'm happy to take solutions using either VBA or built-in Excel functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the highlighted cell, use the following formula: `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A17,$A$2:$A$7,0)),$B$1,$A$1)`

This will work unless the Last Name also is a First Name that appears in your list.

Comment: Thanks, that's a decent solution if the data isn't too large. Unfortunately my real life scenario has to work for 100k rows and 40 columns (around 25 of these contain potential row labels) so to run an IF(ISNA(MATCH on each column could be quite problematic for users with slower machines. I should have mentioned this as a constraint initially!

Comment: Agree, in this case the solution won't be applicable. Can't think of any other workable solution, but to from the compact to the classic view. :-(

Comment: OK, that's what I thought to be honest. On the basis that you answered the original question I'll tick your answer - thanks!